# how to disable empty elements in react js javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am fetching data from an api, in which user can post stuff currently users can post 3 times, but if user has not post 3 time empty box would appear since i added padding and background color for all.. i want to remove all the element who doesnt have any content in them how can i achieve it...

[image]

this is the image, i dont want to show like that

code

```
<pre className='prettyprint' id='forum_detail_code'>
    <code>{data.forumPostCode}</code>
</pre>

<pre className='prettyprint' id='forum_detail_code'>
    <code>{data.forumPostCode}</code>
</pre>

<pre className='prettyprint' id='forum_detail_code'>
    <code>{data.forumPostCode}</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: can you add the map function where you mapping the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally render them by validating the value

```js
{ data?.forumPostCode && <pre className='prettyprint' id='forum_detail_code'>
    <code>{data.forumPostCode}</code>
</pre>}
```

You can do it for all the others. Also you can check the condition based on your value type Like bellow

```
{data?.forumPostCode?.length !== 0 && <pre className='prettyprint' id='forum_detail_code'>
    <code>{data.forumPostCode}</code>
</pre>}
```